# Need help to connect sqlite (e.g. DB.sqlite) in a C# web form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, webforms

I'm creating a C# web forms application with VS2015. I'm stuck on how to access sqlite database (e.g. file DB.sqlite) in it. Even though I can access sqlite database in a WinForm application (nuget SQLite V3.13.0, System.Data.SQLite V1.0.116...etc.)

1. what packages or references I have to nuget or how to add
2. what should I add in Web.config, e.g. the connectionStrings, or others
3. a simple sample code to access DB.sqlite code behinds will be very helpful

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What problem are you having? It should be no different than for a winforms app except you would probably put the connection string in web.config instead of app.config

Comment: If you put your data access code in a separate project from the UI code then the type of UI shouldn't make any difference to how you access the database. A good string to put into your favourite search engine is "repository pattern" (there are other ways than the repository pattern but it's what we use at my day job and I find it works well for me)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes it is no difference from what I’ve done in WinForm. I know the web form must be created as a project then problem got resolved.
Thanks again.
I’ll study more about repository pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with .Net FW 4.8, but you can do like this:

Use Nuget Package Manager to install System.Data.SQLite.Core.

When done it looks like this in packages.config:

```
  <package id="Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework" version="1.0.117.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.117.0" targetFramework="net48" />
```

In Web.Config under `<configuration>` add node with path to the SQLite database:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="SQLite" connectionString="Data Source=C:\temp\database.db;" />   
</connectionStrings>
```

In codebehind Default.aspx.cs add:

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Configuration;
```

And from Page_Load call ReadData() to output text to a `<asp:Literal ID="MyLiteral" runat="server" />`

```
public void ReadData()
{
    using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLite"].ConnectionString))
    {
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = @"SELECT Name FROM Products";
        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var name = reader.GetString(0);
                MyLiteral.Text += name + "<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this can help and save time for someone!

Comment: Thank Xaphod, I believe this helps.